# Python: define a function to calculate sin(x)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have to define a function for calculating `sin()`, and the program will expand the series until the absolute value of the next term in the series is less than `1.0e-7` using this expression:

[image: Expressing the Function sin x as a Series]

This is what I got so far but I know it's way off:

```py
number = input("\n\tEnter X: ")
x_flt = float(number)
x_int = int(x_flt)
x_approx = 0
for i in range(1, x_int+1):
    factor = x_flt * i
def approximate_sin(x):
    '''Insert docstring here.'''
    for a in range():
        x_approx = (-1 ** a * x ** (2 * a + 1)) / factor
    return x_approx
print("\n\tApproximation: {:.10f}".format(float(approximate_sin(x_flt))))
```

Comment: When do you expect this to stop, i.e. where are you comparing anything to `1.0e-7`? Your inner `range()` call probably doesn't do what you want - instead, try to keep track of how much the approximation changes for each iteration by using something like while() and keeping the previous approximation.

Comment: `for a in range():` gives an error since range needs at least one argument).  As mentioned you probably want a while loop that stops when the last term < 1e-7.

Answer (score 3):

Be careful of `-1 ** n`, it isn't parsed as you would expect.  `**` binds more tightly than unary `-` (has higher precedence) so this expression is parsed like `-(1 ** n)`.  Similar to blueteeths solution, I would do something like

```
from math import factorial, pow
from itertools import takewhile, count

large = lambda y: abs(y) > 1e-7

def sin_gen(x):
    for n in count():
        yield (pow(-1, n) * pow(x, (2 * n + 1))) / factorial(2 * n + 1)


def sin(x):
    return sum(takewhile(large, sin_gen(x)))

print(sin(5))  # -0.9589242932128198
```

Answer (score 2):

Given this is an infinite series, you could create a generator that given *x* provides the next evaluation by incrementing *n* each time.

```
from math import factorial, pow

def sin_gen(x):
    n = 0
    while True:
        result = (pow(-1, n) * pow(x, (2 * n + 1))) / factorial(2 * n + 1)
        yield result
        n += 1
```

Now you just need to sum each evaluation until the total is as you want.

```
g = sin_gen(x)
total = 0

for val in g: 
    if abs(val) < 1.0e-7: 
        break 
    total += val

print(total)
```

Comment: @kaya3 That's what I was trying to do with the `val` thing. I always get really confused in this situation. I think this is better?

Comment: @kaya3 Still can't get anywhere near the right answer. Not really sure why. Patrick Haugh has a clever solution anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I would do it, which uses the formula but not directly.

- `(-1) ** n` is the previous value multiplied by `-1`.
- `x ** (2n + 1)` is the previous value multiplied by `x * x`.
- `(2n + 1)!` is the previous value multiplied by `2n * (2n + 1)`.

This means your loop does no power or factorial calculations, which is a bit more efficient. Here it is in Python:

```py
def approx_sin(x, eps=1e-7):
    term = x
    two_n = 0
    total = 0

    while abs(term) >= eps:
        total += term
        two_n += 2
        term *= -x * x / (two_n * (two_n + 1))

    return total
```

Answer (score 1):

**Hints:**

- Add a value to *range(n)*.  Ten iterations would be a good start.
- For *x_approx* use `+=` instead of `=`.
- Perhaps look at [a worked-out example](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#recipes) in the docs.